# lex and yacc warning's and not working as expected

Tags: yacc, lex

Lexer.l

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}

%%

"define" return(TK_KEY_DEFINE); 
"as" return(TK_KEY_AS);
"is" return(TK_KEY_IS);
"if" return(TK_KEY_IF);
"then" return(TK_KEY_THEN);
"else" return(TK_KEY_ELSE);
"endif" return(TK_KEY_ENDIF);
"with" return(TK_KEY_WITH);
"DEFINE" return(TK_KEY_DEFINE_UC);
"AS" return(TK_KEY_AS_UC);
"IS" return(TK_KEY_IS_UC);
"IF" return(TK_KEY_IF_UC);
"THEN" return(TK_KEY_THEN_UC);
"ELSE" return(TK_KEY_ELSE_UC);
"ENDIF" return(TK_KEY_ENDIF_UC);
"WITH" return(TK_KEY_WITH_UC);
"+" return(TK_PLUS);
"-" return(TK_MINUS); 
"*" return(TK_MUL);
"/" return(TK_DIV);
"~" return(TK_NOT); 
"&" return(TK_AND); 
"|" return(TK_OR);
"<=" return(TK_LEQ);
"<" return(TK_LESS);
">=" return(TK_GEQ); 
">" return(TK_GT); 
"==" return(TK_EQ);
"=" return(TK_ASSIGN);
"(" return(TK_OPEN);
")" return(TK_CLOSE);
";" return(TK_SEMI);
"," return(TK_COMMA);
[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]* return(IDENTIFIER);
[+-]?[0-9]+ return(INTEGER);
[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+) return(REAL); 
[[:space:]]+ ;

%%

int yywrap(void)
{
  return 1;
}
```

Parser.y

```
%{

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

  typedef struct node
  {
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    char *token;
  } node;

  node *mknode(node *left, node *right, char *token);
  void printtree(node *tree);

#define YYSTYPE struct node *

%}

%start Program

%token TK_KEY_DEFINE TK_KEY_DEFINE_UC
%token TK_KEY_AS TK_KEY_AS_UC
%token TK_KEY_IS TK_KEY_IS_UC 
%token TK_KEY_IF TK_KEY_IF_UC
%token TK_KEY_THEN TK_KEY_THEN_UC
%token TK_KEY_ELSE TK_KEY_ELSE_UC
%token TK_KEY_ENDIF TK_KEY_ENDIF_UC
%token TK_KEY_WITH TK_KEY_WITH_UC
%token TK_PLUS TK_MINUS
%token TK_MUL TK_DIV
%token TK_NOT
%token TK_AND
%token TK_OR 
%token TK_LEQ TK_LESS TK_GEQ TK_GT 
%token TK_EQ
%token TK_ASSIGN 
%token TK_OPEN TK_CLOSE
%token TK_SEMI
%token TK_COMMA
%token IDENTIFIER
%token INTEGER 
%token REAL


%left   TK_PLUS  TK_MINUS
%left   TK_MUL TK_DIV
%left   TK_LEG TK_LESS TK_GEQ TK_GT 
%left   TK_AND TK_OR
%left   TK_EQ
%right  TK_NOT TK_ASSIGN

%%


Program  : Macros Statements;

Macros   :   /* empty */
         | Macro Macros
         ;

Macro    : TK_KEY_DEFINE MacroTemplate TK_KEY_AS Expression;

MacroTemplate : IDENTIFIER MT;

MT            : /*empty*/
              | TK_OPEN IdentifierList TK_CLOSE 
              ; 

IdentifierList : IDENTIFIER I;

I : /*empty*/
  | TK_COMMA IdentifierList 
  ;

Statements : /*empty*/
           | Statement Statements 
           ;

IfStmt : TK_KEY_IF Condition TK_KEY_THEN Statements TK_KEY_ELSE Statements TK_KEY_ENDIF;

Statement : AssignStmt 
          | IfStmt
          ;

AssignStmt : IDENTIFIER TK_KEY_IS Expression;



Condition : C1 C11;

C11 : /*empty*/
    | TK_OR C1 C11
    ;

C1 : C2 C22;

C22 : /*empty*/
    | TK_AND C2 C22
    ; 

C2 : C3 C33;

C33 : TK_EQ C3 C33;

C3 : C4 C44;

C44 : /*empty*/
    | TK_LESS C4 C44 
    | TK_LEQ C4 C44 
    | TK_GT C4 C44  
    | TK_GEQ C4 C44
    ;

C4 : TK_NOT C5 | C5;

C5 : INTEGER | REAL | TK_OPEN Condition TK_CLOSE;

Expression : Term EE;

EE : /*empty*/
   | TK_PLUS Term EE
   | TK_MINUS Term EE
   ;

Term : Factor TT;

TT : /*empty*/
   | TK_MUL Factor TT 
   | TK_DIV Factor TT 
   ;

Factor : IDENTIFIER | REAL | INTEGER | TK_OPEN Expression TK_CLOSE;

%%

int main (void) {return yyparse ( );}

node *mknode(node *left, node *right, char *token)
{
  /* malloc the node */
  node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  char *newstr = (char *)malloc(strlen(token)+1);
  strcpy(newstr, token);
  newnode->left = left;
  newnode->right = right;
  newnode->token = newstr;
  return(newnode);
}

void printtree(node *tree)
{
  int i;
  if (tree->left || tree->right)
    printf("(");

  printf(" %s ", tree->token);

  if (tree->left)
    printtree(tree->left);
  if (tree->right)
    printtree(tree->right);

  if (tree->left || tree->right)
    printf(")");
}

int yyerror (char *s) 
{
fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
}
```

I wish the output to a parse tree if no errors and indicate error if any . 
But I get a lot of warnings such as

```
 warning: rule useless in grammar 
 warning: nonterminal useless in grammar
```

I understood the reason of this by reading other similar questions but could not correct it myself. Please help me solve this . Thanks !

Hi rici ,

Thank you so much , so I need not worry about left recursion , left factored grammar etc and directly go ahead and use something like below in yacc ?

```
%% 

Program : Macros Statements;

Macros : /*empty*/ 
       |Macro Macros
       ; 

Macro : TK_KEY_DEFINE MacroTemplate TK_KEY_AS Expression;

MacroTemplate : VarTemplate
              | FunTemplate
          ;

VarTemplate : IDENTIFIER;

FunTemplate : IDENTIFIER TK_OPEN IdentifierList TK_CLOSE;

IdentifierList : IDENTIFIER TK_COMMA IdentifierList
               | IDENTIFIER
               ;

Statements : /*empty*/
           | Statement Statements 
           ;

IfStmt : TK_KEY_IF Condition TK_KEY_THEN Statements TK_KEY_ELSE Statements TK_KEY_ENDIF;

Statement : AssignStmt 
          | IfStmt
          ;

AssignStmt : IDENTIFIER TK_KEY_IS Expression;

Condition : Condition TK_AND Condition
          | Condition TK_OR Condition
          | Condition TK_LESS Condition 
          | Condition TK_LEQ Condition
          | Condition TK_GT Condition 
          | Condition TK_GEQ Condition 
      | Condition TK_EQ Condition
          | TK_NOT Condition 
          | TK_OPEN Condition TK_CLOSE
          | INTEGER
          | REAL
          ;

Expression : Expression TK_PLUS Expression
           | Expression TK_MINUS Expression 
           | Expression TK_MUL Expression 
           | Expression TK_DIV Expression 
           | TK_OPEN Expression TK_CLOSE
           | IDENTIFIER 
           | INTEGER
           | REAL
           ;

%%
```

Also yes , I noted your last point :)

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Did you consider mentioning *which* terminals are identified as useless, or did you think that would make your question too easy?

Comment: Ya sorry . Ill keep them in mind next time . Thanks for helping me out here ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `C11`, `C22`, `C44` and other "tail" rules, which can produce `%empty`, `C33` has only one production:

```
C33 : TK_EQ C3 C33;
```

Since it has no non-recursive production, it cannot possibly produce a sentence (consisting only of non-terminals). And since it is part of the only production for `C2` which is part of the only production for `C1` which is part of the only production for `Condition` which is part of the only production for `IfStmt`, none of those can produce any sentence either. A rule which cannot produce any sentence is technically described as "useless" and a non-terminal all of whose rules are useless (or whose only rule is useless) is a "useless non-terminal".

There is another category of useless non-terminals: those which cannot be produced by any useful rule. That will be the case with `C4` (which can only be produced by `C3`, which has been discovered to be useless) and thus with `C44` and `C5`.

It should be evident how to fix that, but I'd like to note that you are tying yourself into knots by trying to avoid left-recursion, which is both unnecessary and counter-productive when using a bottom-up parser generator such as bison/yacc. (See the last paragraph of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350265/shift-reduce-conflict-in-cup/44351047) for a longer grumble about this.) The artificial productions (`C33` and friends) serve only to complicate the parse tree.

Also, since your grammar is not ambiguous -- in effect, the production rules clearly define operator binding strengths -- the various precedence declarations are pointless. (Unlike "useless", that is not a technical term :-) ). Precedence declarations are only applied to resolve grammatical ambiguity, which is not present here.

Finally, I think you should re-examine your grammar for `Condition`s. What, for example, is the meaning of `~3 < ~4`? And why is `x * 2 < y` not valid?